# Java SQLite: How to load an existing database in memory to select faster

Tags: java, sqlite

I have an sqlite database that i query from a java program, no insert, no table creation, just many many SELECT bundled with UNION (500 at a time).
How can I load the database from the .db into memory to speed up the SELECT?

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
String urlJDBC = "jdbc:sqlite:";
String url = urlJDBC + dbPath; 
Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

for(int i=0, i<10000, i++)
{
    String multipleSELECT = "SELECT a FROM table WHERE b=\"" + b1 + "\"" + " 
    UNION ... + " UNION SELECT a FROM table WHERE b=\"" + b500 + "\"";
    Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(multipleSELECT);
    check(rs);
}
```

Obviously the 500 values of b change at every iteration of i.

Is there a way to load the entire database in memory (about 2.5 GB, so less than the 8 GB ram)?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Have you heard about an `IN` query or simply using `OR` instead of `UNION`?

Comment: can you please post the correct query ? this query doe not make sense and explain what are u trying to achieve

Comment: While moving things into memory is often a very efficient way to increase access speed, it's probably not needed here. Your query is just really bad, possibly because you don't understand SQL and databases very well. You'll want to concentrate on that instead of thinking about in memory solutions just yet.

Comment: @luk2302 changing the query to an IN query speeds it up by about 10%, thanks!

Comment: I have a 2 column database (number,name) indexed on the number, I want to check millions of number and if there are in the database return the name.

Comment: I have a 2 column database (number,name) indexed on the number, I want to check millions of number and if there are in the database return the name. So, I do a select query for the number to check, if the resultSet is closed I do nothing, if it is not I write down the result somewhere else. So I have tens of millions of number to check. As suggested by @luk2302, I changed the query to SELECT name FROM table WHERE number IN ("0647854125",...,"0647854125") with 500 numbers in the in. But that gives only 120 numbers checked by seconds, and I want to make it more.

Answer (score 0):

To speed up many small queries, wrap them in a single transaction, and use a single prepared statement with a parameter that changes. Then you should be able to use a simple SELECT that checks only one number.

Alternatively, write all numbers to check into a temporary table, and return all matching names at once:

```sql
SELECT a
FROM MyTable
JOIN TempTable ON MyTable.b = TempTable.b;
```

In either case, you can improve the lookup speed by using a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx), i.e., a two-column index on the number and the name, or, better, by using a [clustered index](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html).